# IntegrityError, NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: django, django-models, integrity

I want to add tags to posts in my Django app.

I can add tags through the admin interface, but when I try to do it through the form I created, I get an IntegrityError.

I couldn't find the solution in the existing topics with the same error. I ran `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

From `models.py`:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False)
    text = models.TextField()

class Tag(models.Model): 
    post = models.ForeignKey('my_app.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tags')
    tag_text = models.CharField()
```

The view:

```
def post_add_tags(request, pk): 
    post= get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST": 
        form = TagForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            tag = form.save()
            tag.post= post
            tag.save()
            return redirect("single_post_view", pk=post.pk)
    else: 
        form = TagForm()
    return render(request, "add_tags.html", {"form": form})
```

The form from `forms.py`:

```
class TagForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ["tag_text"]
```

The template:

```
<form method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Add tags</button>
</form>
```

The error:

> IntegrityError at /post/4/add_tags/
>
> NOT NULL constraint failed: my_app_tag.post_id

I'm using Django version 2.2, Python 3.6.8.

Comment: this line `tag = form.save()`, it should be `tag = form.save(commit=False)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do not `save form` until you set all required fields, specially `foreign keys` :

```
def post_add_tags(request, pk): 
    post= get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST": 
        form = TagForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            tag = form.save(commit=False)
            tag.post= post
            tag.save()
            return redirect("single_post_view", pk=post.pk)
    else: 
        form = TagForm()
    return render(request, "add_tags.html", {"form": form})
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked, but why? In the docs it says "If you call `save()` with `commit=False`, then it will return an object that hasn’t yet been saved to the database. In this case, it’s up to you to call `save()` on the resulting model instance." but, in this case, why couldn't I save it immediately?

Comment: because `post` foreign key will be `null`

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Thanks again!